# crash Dictionary.subscript.getter

Tags: swift, realm, nsmutabledictionary

I'm having several crashes that I've been unable to replicate

```
<compiler-generated> - Line 4370483668
specialized Dictionary.subscript.getter + 4370483668
```

I suspect this might be related with dictionaries not being accessed in a safe way due the use of several threads

The most common crash happens in this line

```
guard self.service?.handlers[id] != nil else {
```

service is a weak variable

any ideas or suggestions?

Do you think a `.async(flags: .barrier)` could solve the issue? because I'm unable to replicate it.

this code is called via *observers* over a **Realm** database so the **Unit test** i've created does several threads that try to write the database at same time.

--UNIT TEST PSEUDO CODE--

```
func testDictionaryAccess()
{
   for i in 0...3
   {
     dispatchGroup.enter()

     DispatchQueue(label: "createActivityThreads").async { 
       create records on database() 
       dispatchGroup.leave() 
     }
   }

   dispatchGroup.wait()
   XCTAssertTrue(true)
}
```

each loop iteration takes about 20 seconds to run

Comment: I don't think there's enough code here to really understand or diagnose the issue. For example, `service` is a week variable... A variable of what? A class? dictionary? Something else? *this code is called via observers over a Realm* - what is being called, what's being observed and what's the process. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) update and refine the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Check this blog post https://medium.com/swiftcairo/avoiding-race-conditions-in-swift-9ccef0ec0b26

Comment: I'm seeing these errors too.  Sometimes even on lines that simply pass a dictionary literal and enum.  Does Swift represent enums as dicitionaries internally??

Comment: @joão-serra, having same kind of issue. please share if you found solution or trick to handle this, Thanks.

Comment: @HardikDarji This was like 3 years ago, I dont quite remember what happen. 

But I read in another posts that this is probably not thread safe.  So my guess is that you must make sure that you always write /read in the same DispatchQueue

In my example i was creating a queue per loop iteration. 
Probably in order to test concurrency at the time to deal with another issue.